# How to add list of users to django admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a model with `start_date` and `end_date`. I would like to add a list of users at the bottom so that an admin can pick from a list of users that are associated with this model.

This is how the model looks in admin panel at the moment

[image]

My model looks like this in `models.py`

```
class MyPeriod(ValidateOnSaveMixin, models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField(unique=True)
    end_date = models.DateField()
```

In `admin.py` I tried adding `filter_horizontal` like this but it gave me errors

```
class MyPeriodAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('start_date', 'end_date',)
    filter_horizontal = ('user',)
```

> The value of 'filter_horizontal[0]' refers to 'user', which is not an
>   attribute of 'MyPeriod'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current model does not contain an association between period and users. You have to specify a ForeignKey relation with the `User` model, such as:

```
from django.conf import settings
...
class MyPeriod(ValidateOnSaveMixin, models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField(unique=True)
    end_date = models.DateField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

After this addition (and applying migrations to reflect the changes to the actual database) you will be able to assign `User`s to your `MyPeriod` model.